# Virtual Linux under Windows with Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, vdi

I've used this in the past but I must have got lucky. Now both Linux OSes I had have been deleted or screwed up but I can't for the life of me remember how I got them installed last time.

I really haven't got a clue, but are these the right steps:

```
(1) Uninstall all the old stuff
(2) Download Virtualbox 5.1.8 and install it
(3) Set up a new machine (eg. "Ubuntu64") and accept most of the defaults
```

I now know that that doesn't give me an OS to run! I need a "VDI" file containing a suitable Linux:

```
(4) Download Linux VDI for Virtualbox, unzip/un7zip etc to .vdi
```

Now is the tricky bit: how to I link this file to the Virtualbox new VM? In Storage, it seems to be set up to this file:

```
 c:\Users\xxxxxx\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.vdi
```

That file exists but is some 2MB. Do I just copy the big .vdi I've just downloaded into that? Because if I do, it gives me an error:

```
UUID {7bfdc68e-2717-4c80-8613-6a2220358337} of the medium 'C:\Users
\xxxxxx\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.vdi' does not match the value
{553bdd10-e133-492f-85b9-3ec2c2fa4e67} stored in the media registry
('C:\Users\xxxxxx\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml').
```

I would have edited that .xml file to match, but the UUID figure in that is different from either of the above! Anyway it seems like there is some official way of telling VB about this vdi; what is it? And if not, what have I done wrong? I downloaded another vdi with the same result.

Comment: `VBoxManage storageattach 553bdd10-e133-492f-85b9-3ec2c2fa4e67 --medium none` followed by `VBoxManage storageattach 553bdd10-e133-492f-85b9-3ec2c2fa4e67 --medium /path/to/new.vdi`.

Comment: (This is c:\program files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VboxManage.exe.) It said --storagectl was missing. I added '--storagectl fred'. It said: 'Could not find a registered machine with UUID {55...}'. I can't believe however that everyone has to go through such a step just to do what must be the essential task of linking a VM to a VDI. Is there something obvious that has been missed?

Comment: Update: used the machine name Ubuntu instead of UUID. The storagectl was 'SATA', and it needed a port number (0). Then it did what it had to do. But trying to start the VM: 'Fatal: could not read from the boot medium!'. Back to where I was yesterday before I upgraded to 5.1.8. In Settings:System:Motherboard, boot order is Floppy first. But they are greyed out. This program is really user-friendly! I might give up I think.

Comment: One more try (this stuff is addictive). A youtube video suggested the boot device needed mounting. Did that (after ungreying the settings by powering off the VM). The 'device' was the vdi file. Now I get the same UUID error I reported in my original post. This could go on for a long time! ... Yikes, I missed out your second step, will do that now...

Comment: OK, THAT WORKED! (Well, not on the first .vdi, but an alternate). Thanks... (Now I just need to locate the terminal window in Linux, minor problems.)

Comment: I encourage you to post an answer. Others might run to this same situation.

Comment: [alvits]I might do but I hardly know what I'm doing, or what I did to fix it. I suspect this is partly luck; next time it might not work. But there might be useful hints in my comments. What's needed is a Dummy's guide for people who want a virtual Linux under Windows or etc, and aren't interested in becoming Virtualbox experts in the process.